# Python, Imports from upper level directory won't work

Tags: python, import

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/three_Positions_plotting
├── ./requirements.txt
├── ./triangulationapi
├── ./venv
├── ./Project_Level
│   ├── ./Project_Level/__init__.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/angle_condition.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/base_objects.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/consts.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/database_consts.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/plot_folium.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/plot_googleMaps.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/postgres_queries.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/test_app.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/test_cases.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/test_database.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/test_utils.py
│   ├── ./Project_Level/utils.py
├── ./triangulationapi/
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/__init__.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/manage.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/requirements.txt.
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/__init__.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/admin.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/apps.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/migrations
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/models.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/second_GDT_finding
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/serializers.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/tests.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/urls.py
│   └   └── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt/views.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/__init__.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/admin.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/apps.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/migrations
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/models.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/serializers.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/tests.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/urls.py
│   │   └── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation/views.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/admin.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/apps.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/__init__.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/migrations
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/models.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/templates
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/tests.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/urls.py
│   │   └── ./triangulationapi/landingpage/views.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/__init__.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/admin.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/apps.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/migrations
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/models.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/serializers.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/templates
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/tests.py
│   │   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/urls.py
│   │   └── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/views.py
│   └── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi
│       ├── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi/__init__.py
│       ├── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi/asgi.py
│       ├── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi/settings.py
│       ├── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi/urls.py
│       └── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi/wsgi.py
```

When trying to import from Project_Level to models in the triangulationapi/.. it raises an error.

```py
# triangulationapi/threelocationstrian/views.py

from Project_Level.base_objects import GeoPoint

# Scrip running ...
```

The output:

```
    from Project_Level.base_objects import GeoPoint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project_Level'
```

This happening all across the project.

and when run directly from the terminal.

This is a cloned project and I used to work on a different machine with this project and the imports did work.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'threelocationstrian',
    'find_second_gdt',
    'KnownLocation'
]
```

tried to change the structure to:

```
├── ./triangulationapi
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/find_second_gdt
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/__init__.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/KnownLocation
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/landingpage
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/manage.py
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/Project_Level
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/__pycache__
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/templates
│   ├── ./triangulationapi/threelocationstrian
│   └── ./triangulationapi/triangulationapi
```

still when I run  the server for example:

```py
python3 manage.py runserver
```

```
# output
from triangulationapi.Project_Level.angle_condition import MeetAngleCond
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'triangulationapi.Project_Level'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite particular directory structure and there is surely a way to fix it, but in general it is a good idea to follow the general setup.

For all django projects, that I know it is the directory with the manage.py file, that is the project's top level and that should be in the python path and that does therefore *not* contain an `__init__.py`

So normally you should import
`KnownLocation`, `landingpage`, `threelocationstrian` and `triangulationapi.settings`

instead of:
`triangulationapi.KnownLocation`, `triangulationapi.landingpage`, `triangulationapi.threelocationstrian` and `triangulationapi.triangulationapi.settings`

can you verify and share the lines, that are in triangulationapi/triangulationapi/settings.py and declare INSTALLED_APPS.
In particular I'm interested whether INSTALLED_APPS contains `KnownLocation`, `landingpage`, `threelocationstrian` or whether it contains `triangulationapi.KnownLocation`, `triangulationapi.landingpage`, `triangulationapi.threelocationstrian`

Can you please elaborate on what you mean with 
'The top folder (above Project_level) is marked as the sources root.'
Are you using an IDE? If yes which one.
Can you also try directly from a command line without any fancy IDE?
and type exactly the commands that you type and mention the directory, that you are in.

Handling your latest answers:

It is confusing, that things worked on your old machine, in my opinion some env vars were set on this machine.

If you still have access to this old machine:
cd to `triangulationapi` and type `echo "$PYTHONPATH"` to see if something was set.

If you just want to make things working on your new machine, then I would propose to  import in your code just from `Project_Level` and *not* from `triangulationapi.Project_Level`

Additionally move either `Project_Level` into the `triangulationapi` directory (next to `manage.py`) or alternatively set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to the parentdirectory of the `Project_Level` dir.

**General comment:**
In general it is asking for trouble to put an `__init__.py` file into a directory from which you execute commands from (like `manage.py`) especially if the parent directory has been added to the python path and if a child directory has the same name than the directory in which you are.
Depending on the import order python can really get lost.

**As general debug recommendation:**
you can add (just prior to the line that fails the import) following snippet. It might shed some light on the issue.

```
import sys
print("PATH:\n", "\n".join(sys.path))
for mod, modinfo in sorted(sys.modules.items()):
    print(mod, modinfo)
```

look in particular out for lines containing `triangulationapi`

Comment: Where can I find that PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: The top folder (above Project_level) is marked as the sources root.

Comment: In fact your tree representation confused me more than it helped me. 
Can you please check whether my edit makes sense?

Will enhance my answeer.

Comment: took your feedback into account,

Comment: I'm using pycharm.

Comment: enhanced the answer

Answer (score 0):

Set up your files as modules and packages. When you import something in python in a directory(make sure you are in that directory) it triggers `sys.path` , which looks for the called file in the parent directory.

Comment: Project_Level has init.py